# How to create repo for multiple Linux distros

Tags: repository

How would I create a mirror for multiple different linux distros on a red hat system? I know you can use `createrepo` on red hat and `apt-mirror` on debian based distros, but the `apt-mirror` package is not available on Red Hat it seems.

I've seen repositories that are basically a "master" repo with packages for every major distribution, yet its running on the same web server. How is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the instructions the distributions give for setting up a (local) mirror. A mirror of a distribution is essentially just a copy of a directory containing the packages and some metadata, no real relationship to the hosting system. Best bet (unless upstream says otherwise) is to use `rsync(1)` to keep the local copy up to date. If you have a copy of installation media, the package collection on it is probably a good starting point.

The commands you cite are for creating a repository given the packages (i.e., add/update the relevant metadata).

To get local installations/updates to use your mirror (and not looking for a mirror advertised by the distribution) is another matter.